# How to restrict automatic account creation in OpenShift Origin 1.3?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

An OpenShift Origin instance can be configured with Google OAuth login with or without a hosted domain restriction. On first login an account is created for the user and then permissions can be assigned.

Is it possible to restrict automatic new account creation, i.e. disable it completely to only allow certain people on the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by choosing which hosted domain you want to use: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#Google .  In addition, you can choose the `lookup` mapping method for users to identities: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#mapping-identities-to-users and tightly control who can and can't have a user on your cluster.

Comment: Thanks, `lookup` is exactly what I've been missing.